# Using "city" on its own in address fields

Tags: word-usage

In forms of the kind where you're supposed to fill in your address, it seems to be much more common to have a slot that says "city" only, rather than "city/town" or "town". Now I'm wondering whether this constitutes an exception from the rule that "city" can only be used about **large** towns? To me, it seems that it would be more logical to have either "city/town" or just "town" on its own (seeing that it seems to be ok to use "town" about cities as well). So, what am I missing here?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I think this is the winning answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In web applications or sites, it is undesirable to have too many alternatives. A person could live in a town, a city, a village, a municipality, a commune, a hamlet, a settlement, etc (all these are official terms somewhere). In England and Wales, a 'city' can be any size. In forms, there is no rule that only a large town or agglomeration of towns can be called a 'city'.

In Britain, at one time, a 'city' could be any place, from village size up, that had a Church of England cathedral (and hence, a Bishop). These have been added to more recently. St Davids in Pembrokeshire, Wales, is Britain’s smallest city by population (1,600).

Comment: Derby, where I live, has had a cathedral since 1927 but was only made a city in 1977!

Comment: I live in London. I struggle when forms insist on "County" or "State"… & just end up having to put London again. I get so many deliveries to 'My address, London, London" that's it's ceased to be funny :\ A cathedral is not a requirement for a city [it's just a common interweb 'factiod']. Birmingham has been a city for over a century & doesn't have a cathedral - https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/what-makes-a-city/

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - same here in Bristol, which was its own county from 1373 to 1974, then part of Avon from then until 1994, and since then a unitary authority. It is not in Gloucestershire or Somerset, and Avon has not existed for nearly 30 years, but the 12-year-olds who design web forms don't get it. In fact county names have not been part of 'fully qualified' postal addresses since postal counties were abolished in 1996.

Comment: tbh, even adding the town/city name these days is just a courtesy. The house number/name & postcode will get it there. [It would be 'smart' for a web form to check the post code matches the street & town, so you don't get a typo of North London/Manchester by swapping an N for an M by mistake]

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - a number of websites I have used recently require only your postcode, and then make you choose what house you live in from a list that drops down.

Comment: Yup, that gives the double-check [though as I have all that kind of info in my auto-fill, I prefer the 'regular' version] …but I'm afraid I have dragged us far off-topic here. ;))

Comment: @gonefishin'again. My OP, so I guess I decide what's on topic, and whereas I agree this exchange may be a bit OT, I thoroughly enjoyed it, so... :)

Comment: The community decides what's on topic, I think, using close votes (for questions) and down votes (for questions and answers), although moderators, of course, have the final say. Some, at least, of these comments address obliquely some of the difficulties of defining a 'city'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, you're right, of course; I was just... not joking, really, but... I wasn't absolutely serious :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just how US postal addresses work.  In the USA, after the name and street you have a line with "City State-code Zip".

Even if you don't live in a "city", you would still have a "City" for your postal address.  You may have an address in "Ten Sleep WY" (pop. 206) but you would still use "Ten Sleep" as your "city".

This works for the USA. It doesn't work in other countries in which English is spoken.  In the UK, for example, you have a "Postal Town", and of course no State code, and it is frustrating to fill in forms designed for Americans when your address doesn't fit American standards.

So in web forms "city" is just something that postal addresses have, and doesn't relate to the population or the size, nor even if the place is incorporated as a city or not.

Comment: Thanks James K! I hate that I can't tick more than one answer as the one solving my question...

Answer (score 1):

I also remember learning the "rule" as a kid that something is a city only if it has more than a certain number of people. I certainly can't remember that number any more. In legal terms, the states within the United States have the ability to cut up their territory however they like; different states may designate population centers as cities, villages, townships (which appears to be a frequent formal term for towns), or other entities according to their own state rules. These rules aren't consistent from state to state.

In real life and conversation, people don't take these distinctions all that seriously. I think most people in the U.S., if pressed to pick one general term, would choose "city."

You mention that people sometimes call cities "towns," but that's more in the direction of slang or irony - I'm reminded of Winston Zeddemore shouting "I love this town!" (in reference to NYC) at the end of Ghostbusters.

Comment: Thank you for an eye-opening answer – I had no idea native speakers don't really make the distinction! As for using "town" about cities, I was thinking more of the fact that dictionaries explain the meaning of "city" in terms of "large town", which to me indicates that "town" would be a hypernym of "town" and "city" in much  the same way as "dog" is a hypernym of "dog" and "bitch", but I guess I've drawn the wrong conclusion here.

Comment: @Helen - London is often called a 'city' but is a conurbation that has absorbed many towns.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Conurbation – what an absolutely lovely word!!

Comment: @Helen In informal speech "town" is often used for a population center of any size, from dozens to millions. In the 19th and early 20th centuries when a person in the UK said "I am going to Town" s/he meant London and nowhere else. This may still be true, I am not sure. In several US states, the state is divided into counties, and each county into townships, which are areas not population centers. In such states all rural land is in some township. In NY state "Town" is used in this same way, as a name for an area that does not form any part of a postal address.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I learn so much from you all! Thanks a million!